# Creating flag for print the output of shell script

Tags: shell

I am creating a shell script. Now, I want to create a flag to print the output of script on the screen if flag is ON otherwise script will not print the output if flag is OFF

Thanks

Comment: In which  place do you want have flag?

Comment: wait, make example...

Comment: Suppose I have script in which `echo "shell script"` is exist and when I execute this script it will print `shell script`. Now I want to create a flag in which if it is ON then print the output on screen which is `shell script` and if flag is OFF then it should not print any thing on screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
# assuming your first argument is the printing flag
[[ "${1}" = "ON" ]] && OUTPUT="/dev/stdout" || OUTPUT="/dev/null"
# from now on:
echo "Something" > $OUTPUT
# will work as expected...
```

Answer (score 0):

test.sh code below:

```
#!/bin/sh
while IFS= read -r line
do
  cat "$line"
done < $1
```

Test it:

```
$ ls
myflags  testfile0  testfile1  testfile2  test.py  test.sh
$ cat myflags 
testfile0
testfile1
test.py
$ cat testfile0
some test
$ sh test.sh myflags 
some test

#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
    sys.stdout.write("ls -l")
$
```